# what is difference between symbolic link file and executable file?

Tags: linux, bash, files, symlink, executable

I was exploring the `/bin` directory. The `/bin` contains file of two different colours, which according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/17299) correspond to:

1. Green indicates executable file
2. Sky blue indicates system link

In bash, I can execute files both of category, for example `ping` (executable) and `cat` (symbolic link).

Should symbolic links also be called executable? How do they differ from each other?

Answer (score 2):

A symbolic link is a file that references another file.  If `/bin/cat` on your system is a symbolic link, then running `ls -l /bin/cat` will show something similar to:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       6 Dec 15  2018 /bin/cat -> some_other_file
```

When you use a symbolic link file, the kernel "follows" the link(s); you end up using the "real" file.  If the "real" file is executable, then you can run that program via the symbolic link (as in your `cat` example).

Symbolic links can point to any other files (plain files, device file, directories, sockets, symbol links, etc); and can point to non-existent files.

You can use the `ln` command with the `-s` flag to create symbolic links.

Comment: I just saw, /bin/cat was referencing to 'coreutils' as u said but both of the files are in same directory. Then what is the use of creating symbolic link?

Comment: What is the purpose of keeping two files on this case?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link

Comment: Example: Let's say you have java 8 and Java 11 installed in separate directories. You could make `java` a symbolic link pointing to one of the two. You could easily change the default Java version by modifying the target of the symbolic link.